# No se detectan las variables con Strings en mi Arduino Uno

Tags: c, arduino

```
String color;
String msg1 = "Escribe un color";

void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
Serial.println(msg1);
while (Serial.available() == 0){
}
color = Serial.readString();

if (color == "verde" || color == "VERDE"){
  Serial.println("Elegiste color verde");
}
if (color == "azul" || color == "AZUL"){
  Serial.println("Elegiste color azul");
}
if (color == "rojo" || color == "ROJO"){
  Serial.println("Elegiste color rojo");
}    
}
```

Cuando en el monitor serial escribo el nombre de los colores (verde, azul, rojo), no entran al if
Estoy usando un arduino uno y uso lenguaje c
[image: Escribo color]
[image: Al presionar enviar no se muestra el mensaje]

Comment: Que raro. Prueba a imprimir la variable color luego de asignarla. Podría darnos una pista de lo que sucede.

Comment: Ya la imprimí y si me sale lo que pongo. Tal vez sea un problema de mi arduino.

Comment: Haz algo más con ello. Imprime el tamaño del string y carácter por carácter. Incluso el número asociado a ese carácter por si a caso. Debe haber un salto de línea, un carácter nulo o algo diferente entre ellos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando lees con `readString()`, también lees el "\n" al final de la línea. Tienes que eliminarlo con

```
color.trim();
```

antes de compararlo.

**Código**

```
String color;
String msg1 = "Escribe un color";

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println(msg1);
  while (Serial.available() == 0) {
  }
  color = Serial.readString();
  color.trim();
  if (color == "verde" || color == "VERDE") {
    Serial.println("Elegiste color verde");
  }
  if (color == "azul" || color == "AZUL") {
    Serial.println("Elegiste color azul");
  }
  if (color == "rojo" || color == "ROJO") {
    Serial.println("Elegiste color rojo");
  }
}
```

#### Demo

[image: Serial Terminal Arduino]

Comment: ¿Qué programa es ese? Se ve interesante.